# What is the best AUTO store switcher for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, extensions, store-switcher

What is the best AUTO store switcher for Magento 2? I have come across a few options just by searching on Google and they all seem to offer similar features. Is Amasty a better provider that Mage Plaza for example? I would love to hear your experience/recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Amasty GeoIp redirect is better one than mageplaza.

> https://amasty.com/geoip-redirect-for-magento-2.html

Comment: And what if I'm a English only speaking UK national traveling through Europe on my way home trying to order something for when I get home?  Don't get me wrong I've used geoip functionality in the past.  And when it works it's great.  When it doesn't work you get abandoned baskets.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion don't automatically switch. This is potentially a method of annoying customers or getting stuck in a loop and they will go elsewhere.

The best option is to automatically show a modal popup or some kind of dialog if they are a new visitor and let the customer decide which version of site they want to use.

Comment: Hi, This will be helpful when you have a multistore setup and there will be the different domains for different countries. For ex: I have the Main store xyz.com and I have multistore setup for UK, Germany, Denmark,Spain like xyz.co.uk, xyz.de, xyz.dk, xyz.es. If you want Spanish customers can landed over to xyz.es and respectively then this module would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Dominic, thank you for sharing your opinion. Are you able to share what module you are utilising for the pop up / dialog you are using?

Comment: So far I've only done this on a Magento 1 store.  Something like this though https://cunningpro.com/website-switcher-geo-ip-website-switcher-magento-2.html

Comment: MageAnts have also created [geo ip store swticher](https://www.mageants.com/geo-ip-store-switcher-for-magento-2.html) for auto store switch